# Fan control during OS installation

Tags: installation, fan

I was curious to know how is the fan controlled during an operating system installation. Since the operating system isnt running during the installation, something else might be controlling the fan speed. In my case, during any installation, the fan doesnt work at all. But once the OS is up and running, the fan works completely normal.
Did anyone had a similiar problem like this?

Comment: By the BIOS, I'd say.

Answer (score 1):

The motherboard BIOS will be controlling the fan speed at the default setting. 
Windows power options has a method of controlling fan speed (system cooling policy), as do many third party applications (e.g. SpeedFan, Aquaero etc).

When you say 'the fan is not running' you are referring to the chassis fan, not the CPU fan? If the CPU fan is not running at all during OS install, it may be worth double checking - though most motherboards would fail to POST if the fan speed is reported below a certain threshold.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is the fan speed in BIOS configurable? I have never seen such an option in the BIOS. I am using a laptop and hence it is unfortunately the CPU fan. Can someone refer some weblinks for the process of running CPU fans starting from BIOS?

Comment: It depends on the motherboard - the option can be basic set percentage or linked to CPU temp. Sometimes the option is hidden under a 'PC health' menu and/or a manual override. You would have to refer to laptop manual to see if this is an available option.